# Too small annotation iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, mapkit

I have made an application which simulates movement of buses on a map.

The buses are MKAnnotations moving atop a MKMapview. By touching the annotation/bus, it will show a custom made callout with info about the bus. It is all based upon public realtime data.

A problem I have is that the MKAnnotations (buses) are very small, and since they are constantly moving, it is often hard to touch the annotation to show the callout.

The icon is 25x25 pixels, and can not be increased.

Is there any way to make an invisible rect which will increase the touch-sensitive area around an annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a larger annotation view and set the background color to [UIColor clearColor].
Create a 25x25 UIImageView and add it to the annotation view. You can set the frame of the ImageView to place it in the center of the annotation view.

Comment: Thanks. Nice and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it non-programmatically.

Using photoshop, I made a 75x75pix 100% opaque picture, and added my 25x25pix icon on top.

Maybe not the best solution, but it worked.